# Subtitle Overlapping: How to comparing two timelines in subtitles (e.g. 00:18:06 vs 00:16:01) and overwriting one of them if it's overlapping?

Tags: awk, subtitle

I have a series of srt files (film subtitles) that some of their time-lines overlap each others on the video! This means that some of time-lines are displayed about 1-2 seconds longer than they are in the film and conflict with the next ones!

for example:

```
1
00:00:01.000 --> 00:00:07.000
The following content is provided

2
00:00:04.000 --> 00:00:10.000
under a Creative Commons license.
```

'07' overlaps '04'!

I want to overwrite the first part of time-lines on the 2nd part of their previous line. Be care that all time-lines do not interfere with each other. some of them are correct and shorter than their next timeline! The interference is only to some of them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "If B Do nothing".

Comment: and that's what the code already does. Could you show an example where it doesn't?

Comment: If you have access to the original video (with subtitles) you can extract clean subtitles (with no overlaps) using ccextractor as `ccextractor VIDEO.mp4 -noru -o SUBS.srt`

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question on [#awk IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=awk) an [@geirha](https://askubuntu.com/users/9016/geirha) wrote the below great scripts. The script may be usable for other people. Subtitles overlapping problem is common because of Human error during subtitling a movie!

Suppose your timelines are in the below format:
`A --> B`
`C --> D`

Replacing B with C:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS = "";
    OFS = FS = "\n";
    getline;
    n = split($0, prev_rec);
    split($2, prev_time, / --> /);
  }
  {
    split($2, a, / --> /);
    if (a[1] < prev_time[2])
      prev_rec[2] = prev_time[1]" --> "a[1];
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
      print prev_rec[i];
    printf("\n");
    n = split($0, prev_rec);
    split($2, prev_time, / --> /)
  }
  END {
    print
  }' SUBTITLE.srt > RESULT.srt
```

The above code compare **B** and **C** in this way:

If B > C => then run that charming command to replace B.
If B < C => Do nothing!

---

Replacing C with B:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {
    RS="";
    OFS=FS="\n";
    prev="00:00:00"
  }
  {
    split($2,a,/ --> /);
    if
      (a[1] < prev) $2=prev" --> "a[2];
      print $0"\n"; prev=a[2]
  }' SUBTITLE.srt > RESULT.srt
```

---

To use scripts on some amount of srt files in a folder:

```
for file in *.srt
  do xxx "$file" > "$file.tmp" && mv "$file.tmp" "$file";
done
```

Replace **xxx** with the right script codes!